# How to remove back to top in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I need to remove back to top, This is the html code : Top But however i cannot find this code or element id anywhere in web directory, I tried removing style from css, yet the top text remains, if anyone can help me please let me know

Comment: <a title="Top" href="#top">Top</a>

Comment: Can you share more? Screen? Link to website? What theme you use etc. ?
Is this html code generated via JS or server side?

Comment: This is html generated code via js, Please visit splentit.com to see for your self

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I've checked the website and I could see this element in dev tools.
When scrolling page I saw JS sets inline style for it so I set breakpoint on this element

[image: Setting a breakpoint]

so when scrolling it stopped in one of Jquery method. Then using call stack panel I found the source:

[image: Script responsible for adding a go to top element]

So you need to override **themecore.min.js**

As far as I've checked it's not easy to add mixin for this js script. So you need to replace this file with version and remove backToTop method call with method itself.

```
themecore.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.triggerAdaptScreen();
    this.triggerAdaptScreen(1200);

    ... // some code - I've cut it to make example short

    this.remoteSliderNav();
    this.backToTop(); // remove this line
    this.scrollTo();
    this.mobiProductViewTabs();
```

and then you can remove:

```
themecore.stickyMenu = function() {
    $('.js-sticky-menu').attr('data-mage-init', '{"themewidgets": {"codazon.stickyMenu": {}}}');
}
// remove this part below:
themecore.backToTop = function() {
    if ($('#back-top').length == 0) {
        $('<div id="back-top" class="back-top" data-role="back_top"><a title="Top" href="#top">Top</a></div>').appendTo('body');
    }
    $('[data-role="back_top"]').each(function() {
        var $bt = $(this);
        $bt.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                'scrollTop': 0
            }, 800);
        });
        function toggleButton(hide) {
            if (hide) {
                $bt.fadeOut(300);
            } else {
                $bt.fadeIn(300);
            }
        }
        var hide = ($(window).scrollTop() < 100);
        toggleButton(hide);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var newState = ($(window).scrollTop() < 100);
            if (newState != hide) {
                hide = newState;
                toggleButton(hide);
            }
        });
    });
}
// end of removing
themecore.b64DecodeUnicode = function(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

Other option would be to run JS after this script init module and remove this element but I would prefer to cut down amount of JS code if not used.

Idealy if author of this themecore script would split it into smaller files so you could override/mixin only part of the code so updates will be easier.

Overriding whole file you need to remember about future updates of this file.

**How to replace this file?**
You need find where/how themecore is initalized.

Then I guess this docs will help you:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html